# Использование итераторов С++ с массивами

Tags: c++, итераторы

Возможно, кто-либо может объяснить итераторы и их использование с массивами, или же дать соответствующую литературу по этой теме?

Т.к. я читал по разным книгам о итераторах, но там идет речь о использовании их совместно с STL и т.п., а как самому написать - особо такого не написано... Насколько я понял, то они нужны, чтобы перебирать и т.п. элементы массива. Я правда не знаю смысл в этом, если вроде бы можно и непосредственно обращаться, ну да ладно, не важно.
Т.е. нужно создать вложенный класс внутри класса, где будет содержаться, скажем, массив?

Если я понял, то в конце концов, когда он написан, то, к примеру, для цикла выведения массива будет такой код:

```
for(start = Iterator.begin(); start != end; start++)
{
    cout << *start;
}
```

Или я что-то путаю?

P.S.: А ещё, если у кого есть книги, где об этом говорится, статьи, то пожалуйста и их напишите тоже сюда.

---

```
class Array
{
private:
    int* p;
public:
    class Iterator
    {
        public:
        Iterator()  
        {
            p = nullptr;
        }
        Iterator(int *pv)
        {
            p = pv;
        }
        int operator *() const
        {
            return *p;
        }
        Iterator operator ++(int)
        {
            int *temp = p;
            return ++temp;
        }
    };

    Array();
    ~Array();
int& operator[] ();
    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(buffer_)
    }
int* buffer_;

void partial_sort(Array::Iterator start, Iterator end)
{
    start
}
```

Вот как понять что-то вроде этого... Точнее говоря это наброски, они не совсем мои.. Вот мне нужно сделать примерно такое же, только работающее..

---

Если говорить поконкретнее насчёт того, что не понимаю...
Вот класс итератор вложенный, в нем какое поле должно быть ?
При перегрузке `Iterator operator ++(int)` это он типо должен будет перебирать элементы массива же, да?
А если я хочу перегрузить ==?
Я пробовал писать что-то вроде:

```
Iterator operator==(Iterator it1, Iterator it2)
```

Чтобы сравнивать их на равенство, но не получается - ошибка "много аргументов".
ДА и ещё не до конца понимаю как его реализовать..
Т.е. допустим функции вывода, сортировок вместо того, чтобы передавать массив и его длину мне нужно будет передавать 2 итератора, верно? Один из них указывает на начало, другой на конец, да?
А вывод массива в таком случае выглядел бы с итераторами так:

```
for(start ???; start != end; start++)
  cout << *start;
```

Comment: Вот книга Шилдта страница №808 и далее там про это говорится.[Ссылка на файл][2]


  [2]: http://sourse.my1.ru/shildt-cpp.rar

Comment: Спасибо за книгу Шилдта, но... простите, вы случаем не описались страниецй? - Там просто всего страниц 791.

Comment: Для справки:
Я читал про итераторы (соответствующие главы) в книгах:
Лафоре, Шилдта, Лаптева, Дейтела, Прата, Страуструпа, Савич...
Нигде именно того, что подошло бы мне, к сожалению, не нашлось...

Comment: Эх... 
Если бы было так просто нагуглить - я бы не задавал вопрос)
Википедия это было пожалуй первое, что я прочёл)

Comment: Вы эта... пока с перегрузкой не парьтесь. Все равно операторы - это по сути функции. Поэтому нужно написать мясо - сами ф-ции, которые будут делать осмысленные вещи, а затем уже заниматься перегрузкой. ИМХО.

Comment: Да я понимаю... Но просто нужно сделать именно с перегрузкой...

Comment: Самый простой пример кода таков - http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator/cpp/2

Comment: И вообще на самом деле смысла реализовывать свои итераторы на C++, конечно, нет, т.к. есть STL, которую можно использовать на все 100%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот, собственно, пример итератора. Этот код вырезан из SGI STL, почищен от всяких подробностей, чтобы оставить суть. Тут можно посмотреть что и как в итераторах должно быть в принципе:

```
#include <cstddef> // нужен только лишь для типа std::size_t

class iterator
{
protected:
  int* p;

public:
  explicit iterator(int* __i) : p(__i) { }

  // Forward iterator requirements
  const int& operator*() const
  { return *p; }

  int& operator*()
  { return *p; }

  int* operator->() const
  { return p; }

  // prefix increment (++it)
  iterator& operator++() {
      ++p;
      return *this;
  }

  // postfix increment (it++)
  iterator operator++(int)
  { return iterator(p++); }

  // Bidirectional iterator requirements

  // prefix decrement (--it)
  iterator& operator--() {
      --p;
      return *this;
  }

  // postfix decrement (it--)
  iterator operator--(int)
  { return iterator(p--); }

  // Random access iterator requirements
  const int& operator[](const std::size_t& __n) const
  { return p[__n]; }

  int& operator[](const std::size_t& __n)
  { return p[__n]; }

  iterator& operator+=(const std::size_t& __n)
  { p += __n; return *this; }

  iterator operator+(const std::size_t& __n) const
  { return iterator(p + __n); }

  iterator& operator-=(const std::size_t& __n)
  { p -= __n; return *this; }

  iterator operator-(const std::size_t& __n) const
  { return iterator(p - __n); }

  int* base() const { return p; }
};

// Forward iterator requirements
inline bool
operator==(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() == __rhs.base(); }

inline bool
operator!=(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() != __rhs.base(); }

// Random access iterator requirements
inline bool
operator<(const iterator& __lhs,
      const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() < __rhs.base(); }

inline bool
operator>(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() > __rhs.base(); }

inline bool
operator<=(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() <= __rhs.base(); }

inline bool
operator>=(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() >= __rhs.base(); }

inline std::size_t
operator-(const iterator& __lhs, const iterator& __rhs)
{ return __lhs.base() - __rhs.base(); }

inline iterator
operator+( std::size_t __n, const iterator& __i)
{ return iterator(__i.base() + __n); }
```

Обратите внимание на explicit конструктор, на то какие операторы перегружены для того, чтобы итератор удовлетворял концепциям:

- forward iterator
- random access iterator
- bidirectional iterator

Comment: Спасибо, будут разбираться.

Answer (score 2):

Массив - это конкретная форма хранения данных. Отличается тем, что у нас есть числовой индекс у каждого элемента. Причем этот индекс уникален. Обычно эти индексы представляют собой целые числа от некоего минимального до некоего максимального с каким-то фиксированным шагом.

```
int a[100];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    std::cout<<a[i]; //вывести на экран i-тый элемент массива
}
```

Когда стандартный массив начинает не устраивать, то можно сделать специальный класс, который будет перегружать оператор [] и будет выглядеть как массив. Но при этом внутренняя структура может быть, например, связанным списком или еще чем-то более хитрым. Все зависит от задач.

Далее - никто не мешает перегрузить этот оператор так, чтобы он принимал, например, строчку. Это удобно для создания структур данных типа словаря. Наличие численных индексов становится уже необязательно.

Но при этом в любом случае возникает задача обеспечения возможности поэлементного перебора элементов такого "массива". Вот тут-то и появляется итератор. Это некая штука, которая знает как перебирать элементы. Опять же внутренняя реализация нас, как пользователя, не волнует. А с точки зрения разработчика мы можем ее сделать оптимизированной под конкретную задачу. Итераторы бывают разных типов: пассивные, активные - в зависимости от того как они соотносятся с классом, для которого используются. Об этом всем хорошо написано в книжке Джеффа Элджера "C++.Библиотека программиста", изд. Питер.

PS: в качестве типа массива в свежих компиляторах я бы рекомендовал использовать шаблонный тип std::array.

Comment: А можно многабукаф превратить во что то более читабельное? И поподробнее про итераторы?

Comment: Не понял. А что с сообщением случилось? Глюки форматирования, что ли?

Comment: Прочёл, спасибо конечно, но вот насчёт:
"PS: в качестве типа массива в свежих компиляторах я бы рекомендовал использовать шаблонный тип std::array."
В том то и дело - нужно написать самому итератор..
Т.е. у меня есть класс, есть вложенный класс Iterator, мне и нужно этот итератор написать и использовать его...
(я буду при сортировках использовать, при выводе на экран и т.п.)
(т.е. нужно будет ещё перегрузить несколько операций, как я понимаю)

Comment: ОК, сейчас намутим пример.

Comment: Спасибо)
Буду ждать)

Answer (score 2):

Итераторы призваны предоставлять доступ к членам контейнеров, они могут быть использованы способом, похожим на манипуляции указателями. Например, можно использовать итератор для прохода по всем элементам вектора. Есть несколько разных типов итераторов.

Каждый класс контейнеров связан с типом итератора, и каждый из алгоритмов STL использует определенный тип итератора.

Например, векторы связаны с итераторами с произвольным доступом, значит, они могут использовать алгоритмы, требующие произвольного доступа. Так как итераторы с произвольным доступом включают в себя все свойства других итераторов, то векторы также могут использовать алгоритмы, написанные для других итераторов.

Код в примере создает итератор и использует его в векторе:

```
    vector<int> the_vector;
    vector<int>::iterator the_iterator;

    for( int i=0; i < 10; i++ ) 
       the_vector.push_back(i);
    int total = 0;
    the_iterator = the_vector.begin();
    while( the_iterator != the_vector.end() ) {
      total += *the_iterator;
      ++the_iterator;
    }

    cout << "Итого=" << total << endl;
```

Получить доступ к элементам контейнера можно путем разыменования итератора.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснения)
Но опять таки... Дело в том, что мне не STL, мне нужно написать итератор для массива...

Answer (score 2):

В принципе итератор, это просто расширенная концепция указателя и все алгоритмы STL, работающие с итераторами должны работать и с указателями напрямую:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>

void go( int value )
{
    printf("%d\n", value);
}

int main()
{
    int a[5] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    std::for_each( &a[0], &a[5], &go );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyIterator;
class MyArray{
public:
    MyIterator* Iterate();  // возвращает пассивный итератор, index в 0.
    bool More(MyIterator*); // true если еще есть элементы, иначе - false
    int Next(MyIterator*);  // возвратим текущий элемент массива, index++
    ...
};
class MyIterator
{
     int index;  // здесь мы будем хранить номер текущего элемента
     // для конкретного итератора, т.к. итераторов мы можем завести много.
     ...
}

MyArray* collection = new MyArray(100);// сделаем-ка массив на 100 элементов,
// для этого конструктор коллекции должен принимать кол-во элементов
...
MyIterator* iter = collection->Iterate(); //сделаем итератор
... 
while (collection->More(iter)) // пока еще есть элементы
    std::cout<<collection->Next(iter)<<std::endl; // выведем текущий элемент.
```

Криво, но похоже на правду.

Comment: Контейнер (класс, описывающий массив) предлагаю описать самому.

Comment: Спасибо, уже попонятнее стало с одной стороны...
Ну вот я добавил в вопрос, точнее отредактировал своё первое сообщение (собственно сам вопрос)...

Answer (score -2):

Есть классная книга: "С++. Методики программирования Шилдта". там примерно половина посвящена итераторам